# Trim something from a cell with multiple data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to seek your expertise in getting this task done.

All information are actually in one cell so i need to extract those information to their corresponding cells.

[image]

I appreciate the help

Comment: Do you have access to original source of "Data" ?

Comment: For a VBA solution, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261957/how-to-split-string-into-cells-for-multiple-cells/38262071.  Maybe you could place ": " for the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your first "data" cell is in A3, here are the formulas I came up with that you can copy down each column.

Column B:

```
=MID(A3,SEARCH("Name: ",A3)+LEN("Name: "),SEARCH("Email:",A3)-(SEARCH("Name: ",A3)+LEN("Name: ")))
```

Column C:

```
=MID(A3,SEARCH("Email: ",A3)+LEN("Email: "),SEARCH("Name:",A3,SEARCH("Name:",A3)+1)-(SEARCH("Email: ",A3)+LEN("Email: ")))
```

Column D:

```
=MID(A3,SEARCH("Name: ",A3,SEARCH("Name: ",A3)+1)+LEN("Name: "),SEARCH("Email: ",A3,SEARCH("Email: ",A3)+1)-(SEARCH("Name: ",A3,SEARCH("Name: ",A3)+1)+LEN("Name: ")))
```

Column E:

```
=RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH("Email: ",A3,SEARCH("Email: ",A3)+1)-LEN("Email: ")+1)
```

PS: When I see the word "referee" I assume a person officiating sports :P

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!